# How Text field value change when add or subtact using jquery?

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart, cart

I Want to change Shopping Cart Text field value when add or subtract product from cart. I mean i just want text field with changing values when click add or minus buttons..just like changing number of items in a shopping cart.

[image: Reffer Image]

Comment: What you mean shopping cart?? is that your own custom shopping cart script?? or another shopping cart script like open cart??

Comment: i mean i just want text field with changing values when click add or minus buttons..just like changing number of items in a shopping cart.

Answer (score 3):

Use your HTML as follow. I've tried to make it more dynamic.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/x5y3zp98/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product').on('click', '.add', function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val(parseInt($(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val(), 10) + 1);
  }).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val(), 10) > 0) {
      $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val(parseInt($(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val(), 10) - 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.product div {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.remove {
  color: red;
}
.add {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product_1" class="product">
  <div class="remove">-</div>
  <input type="text" id="product_qty_1" value="1">
  <div class="add">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.minus').on('click',function(){

   if(parseInt($('#textbox').val() > 0){

      $('#textbox').val(parseInt($('#textbox').val()) - 1);

     }
});
$('.plus').on('click',function(){

  $('#textbox').val(parseInt($('#textbox').val()) + 1);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1cjLxtrk/7/

I hope above answer will help you.

Comment: Click on minus button when value is 0 will make it go below zero, which is not intended.

Comment: Yes, Agreed! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following boostrap code should be more helpful

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Simple Quantity increment buttons with Javascript </h2>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="10" min="1" max="100">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quantitiy = 0;
    $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());

        $('#quantity').val(quantity + 1);
    });
    $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());

        // Increment
        if (quantity > 0) {
            $('#quantity').val(quantity - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

The resultant fiddle is

https://jsfiddle.net/kurms2c4/